close one’s worldly account (the meaning of the word 'account')

close one’s worldly account

What's the meaning of 'account' here?

You're going to need to provide some context.

There is no meaning to be gained from an out-of-context sentence fragment. Voting to close as lacking details. My guess is this is some kind of extended metaphor dealing with death in the language of commerce, but that's a shot in the dark at this point.

@AndyBonner the phrase is from a dictionary and it translated the phrase into like 'get out of this material world'


When a question lacks details, please use the "Edit" button below it to add details in the question rather than clarifying in the comments section. 2) So, you encountered the phrase out of context. Sounds like my guess was right. "Account" is being used as a metaphor; see definitions of "account" (or if you don't find clear answers, edit to tell about what you found).


This text is translated from German. It's contextually obvious that when it says Hausser "closed his worldly account" in 1867, that's when he died.

@FumbleFingers - in French a person might 'swallow their birth certificate'. The perils of trying to translate idioms.

@MichaelHarvey: Parce que les keufs voudraient qu'tu ravales ton extrait d'naissance. I never knew that one. I never knew this German one either, and when I searched in Google Books I could only see 4 lines of text. I guessed it meant "die", but just to be sure I googled hauser died 1867 (not noticing it should have been hausser). Would you believe it? The first 4 results returned were for four different Hausers all born in 1867. Not one that died! But all became clear when I noticed the missing 's' and searched again!

@FumbleFingers - I think it's a safe (-ish) bet that all of the Hausers (and Haussers) born in 1867 have died by now. That 'French' quote looks a bit like Verlan (on veut kiffer les meufs etc). I would say il a avalé son bulletin de naissance also il est clamsé, il a passé l'arme à gauche, il a cassé sa pipe, [and my favourite] il mange les pissenlits par la racine. This last is our pushing up daisies, isn't it?

@MichaelHarvey: Apparently in 1998 Thatcher didn't get the joke of "This party is no more...it has ceased to be... this is an EX-party", but I'd say that particularly emphatic prefix has definitely entered the BrE lexicon for the foreseeable future.  The entire immortal sketch invoked in a single syllable!

@FumbleFingers - I find that younger people don't get 'tired and shagged out after a long squawk'.

@FumbleFingers - when I was 14 my best pal at school told me he was amused (but knew better than to show it) when his father said 'I'm afraid your grandpa's pegged out'.

@MichaelHarvey: I've used peg out for both #1 die and #2 win (a game of e.g. cribbage) since I was a kid (also peg it, but only in the first sense). But I never realized until I just googled it that metaphoric sense #1 is thought to derive from the literal usage #2. I actually thought it might be to do with marking out the rectangle to dig a grave (as a teenager working on building sites I sometimes encountered "peg out" for measuring / marking a building plot prior to digging the footings and drain ditches).

@FumbleFingers - my wife and I share a grim sense of humour; we dry our washing on a clothes line if the weather is good. We often say cheerfully 'I'm going in the garden to peg out'.

@FumbleFingers - I still remember fondly an irreverent female colleague I had in 1997. Princess Diana had been killed over the weekend, and on the Monday we were all discussing it. My colleague said 'Yesterday morning I put the radio on, and it was just solemn music. I immediately thought that the Queen Mum had carked it!'. I, and some others, laughed. Some older people glared.

This is a figurative use of "account" to mean all the actions of a person. "worldly account" means everything they've done during their life in the real world. It's intended to contrast with the afterlife.
So "closed his worldly account" means he died.
There are many metaphors and euphemisms for dying (e.g. "passed on", "gone to meet his maker"), because people have often found it uncomfortable to talk about directly.
